# Formatting in HoverTool

Tags: python, bokeh

I love how easy it is to set up basic hover feedback with HoverTool, but I'm wrestling with a couple aspects of the display. I have time-series data, with measurements that represent amounts in US$. This data starts out life as a `pandas.Series`. Legible plotting is easy (following assumes jupyter notebook):

```
p = figure(title='Example currency', x_axis_type='datetime',
           plot_height=200, plot_width=600, tools='')
p.line(my_data.index, my_data)
p.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format='$0,0')
show(p)
```

This shows me the time-series, with date-formatting on the x-axis and y-axis values that look like "$150,000", "$200,000", "$250,000", etc. I have two questions about `HoverTool` behavior:

- Controlling formatting for `$x` and `$y`.
- Accessing the name of the dataset under the cursor.

Simply adding a `HoverTool` allows me to see values, but in unhelpful units:

```
p.add_tools(HoverTool())
```

The corresponding tooltip values with these defaults show "1.468e+5" rather than "$146,800" (or even "146800", the underlying `Series` value); similarly, the date value appears as "1459728000000" rather than (say) "2016-04-04". I can manually work around this display issue by making my `pandas.Series` into a `ColumnDataSource` and adding string columns with the desired formatting:

```
# Make sure Series and its index have `name`, before converting to DataFrame
my_data.name = 'revenue'
my_data.index.name = 'day'
df = my_data.reset_index()
# Add str columns for tooltip display
df['daystr'] = df['day'].dt.strftime('%m %b %Y')
df['revstr'] = df['revenue'].apply(lambda x: '${:,d}'.format(int(x)))
cds = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure(title='Example currency', x_axis_type='datetime',
           plot_height=200, plot_width=600, tools='')
p.line('day', 'revenue', source=cds)
p.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format='$0,0')
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[('Amount', '@revstr'), ('Day', '@daystr')]))
show(p)
```

but is there a way to handle the formatting in the `HoverTool` configuration instead? That seems much more desirable than all the data-set transformation that's required above. I looked through the documentation and (quickly) scanned through the source, and didn't see anything obvious that would save me from building the "output" columns as above.

Related to that, when I have several lines in a single plot, is there any way for me to access the `name` (or perhaps `legend` value) of each line within `HoverTool.tooltips`? It would be extremely helpful to include something in the tooltip to differentiate which dataset values are coming from, rather than needing to rely on (say) line-color in conjunction with the tool-tip display. For now, I've added an additional column to the `ColumnDataSource` that's just the string value I want to show; that obviously only works for datasets that include a single measurement column. When multiple lines are sharing an underlying `ColumnDataSource`, it would be sufficient to access the column-name that's provided to `y`.

Comment: See https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/1239 for the datetime issue (Your workaround is the only way right now)

Answer (score 2):

Hey i know its 2 years late but this is for other people that come across this

```
 p.add_tools(HoverTool(
tooltips=[
            ('Date',    '@Date{%F}'),
            ('Value',   '@Value{int}')],
formatters={
'Date':'datetime',
'Value':'numeral'},mode='vline'
))
```